# babel: Understanding the starred version of \babelfont (i.e. difference between script and font)

Tags: fonts, babel, arabic

For the following MWE, I need to understand

1- when I should use the starred version of `\babelfont[*arabic]` and

2- the differences between/impact of setting the language `arabic` and the script `*arabic`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
Ligatures = {
    NoCommon, % liga
    NoRare,% dlig
}
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Scheherazade}[ Script = Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}, Scale = 1]

\usepackage[english, bidi = basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Scheherazade} % [Scale = 2]{Scheherazade}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}{Scheherazade}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s suppose you are writing a book in French on the Arabic script. Here is a minimal setup:

```tex
\documentclass[french]{book}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}

\babelfont[*arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

Français \foreignlanguage{arabic}{العربية} français
\foreignlanguage{persian}{فارسی} français
\foreignlanguage{uyghur}{ئۇيغۇرچە} français.

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\babelfont[*arabic]{rm}{Amiri}` presets the font for *all* languages
using the Arabic *script* at once. This is what `*arabic` with the star means. With `arabic` without the star, only the font for the Arabic *language* would be preset, and not for Persian or Uyghur. Note I've said *preset*, because the font is not actually loaded if not necessary.

I’d like to highlight several points:

- The main language can be set as either a class or a package option. This is the standard way in LaTeX to set the document language. Here I opted for the class option.
- However, and following the customary practice in many systems, there is usually no need to declare explicitly at the beginning of the document other languages for just a few words or phrases, because they are loaded on the fly if required.
- There are variations, of course. You may want to declare all languages explicitly, for example. You may also want to create short commands like `\textpersian` (with `\babeltags`), but for the reasons explained in the manual (mainly because the `\text...` prefix is heavily overloaded) this isn’t recommended.

Comment: Very informative! I assume `\textparsian` should be `\textpersian`. As you know, I also usually pair Amiri with Khaled Hosny’s other font Libertinus.

Comment: @Davislor Oops! `\textpersian`, of course (fixed). Definitely, CM and Amiri don’t match, but it’s a minimal setup, after all .

Comment: What is the meaning of using an Arabic script for another language (e.g. French)?

Comment: @Diaa The Arabic script is used in the Arabic language, Farsi, Urdu... But consider a book written in French explaining how this writing system works. Of course, the French text is written in the Latin script.

Comment: Is it possible to list all the languages that use the Arabic script?

Comment: @Diaa `babel` provides complete or partial support for the following languages: Uzbek, Urdu, Uyghur, Turkmen, Pashto, Punjabi, Mazanderani, Northern Luri, Kashmiri, Northern Kurdish, Persian, Central Kurdish, Arabic.